# Getting "java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException" when trying to run gradle project with Netbeans

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans, google-drive-api

I followed this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KaOfbJN7WRQ , and everything works correctly, I can execute the upload of the file to google drive using "gradle run" from the cmd. But when I try to run the project using Netbeans I get the following error:

```
JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.3"
cd C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DriveProyect; .\gradlew.bat --configure-on-demand -x check run
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE

> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE

> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :run FAILED
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DriveProyect\tokens

    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:96)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsAclFileAttributeView.getFileSecurity(WindowsAclFileAttributeView.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsAclFileAttributeView.getOwner(WindowsAclFileAttributeView.java:122)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.FileOwnerAttributeViewImpl.getOwner(FileOwnerAttributeViewImpl.java:91)
    at com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory.setPermissionsToOwnerOnlyWindows(FileDataStoreFactory.java:157)
    at com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory.<init>(FileDataStoreFactory.java:77)
    at DriveProyect.getCredentials(DriveProyect.java:65)
    at DriveProyect.main(DriveProyect.java:78)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.3\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 894ms

This is the code structure that contains lines 65 (`throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);`) and 78(`return credential;`) :

    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT)
      throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = DriveProyect.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    if (in == null) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    }
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
        GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder( HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
        .setAccessType("offline")
        .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    //returns an authorized Credential object.
    return credential;
  }
```

I don't understand what could be the error, I searched and it seems that the Gradle plugin is well installed in my Netbeans 13. [my project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AhnA.png)

Comment: hmm I might be mistaken here, but it could be the path.

Can you try DriveProyect.class.getResourceAsStream("tokensFileOnlyWithoutPath"), as I believe that it will look under your resources in NetBeans/YourProject

Comment: Hi JCompetence, I tried what you told me but nothing happens, Netbeans throws another error "Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource not found: /credentials.json"